# How can I change the description of a power plan in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, power-management

I used the `powercfg` utility within windows to duplicate a power plan that my Samsung SSD software created and I would like to change the description of the new plan.

Comment: I opted for [tag:windows] rather than [tag:windows-8] or [tag:windows-8.1] because I this applies to at least Windows 7 as well (I tested in a VM) and ironically the initial output of `powercfg /?` is more detailed on Windows 7 than Windows 8.1. How about that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use the `changename` command and specify the description after the name, like so:

```
powercfg /changename <guid> "Plan name here" "Plan description here"
```

This happens to be all the parameters you can pass to the `changename` command, with its full syntax being:

```
powercfg /changename <scheme_guid> <name> [<description>]
```

I have verified that this works on at least Windows 7 and 8.

It may also be worth noting that (at least in Windows 7 and 8) the slashes prefixed to the commands in `powercfg` can be omitted, with `powercfg changename <guid> <name> [<description>]` being perfectly valid.

Comment: Yup, can even use hyphens in place of slashes for options.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Go go MS being all flexible and whatnot :)